# Adiabatic expansion in van der Waals gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, adiabatic

Given a Van der Waals gas with state equation:
$$\left( P+\frac{N^2 a}{V^2}\right)\left( V-Nb \right)=NkT,$$
show that the equation of an adiabatic process is:
$$\left( V-Nb\right)T^{C_V}=\text{constant}.$$

I began by setting $đQ=0$ in
$$\mathrm dU=đQ+đW,$$
one then gets 
$$0=\mathrm dU+P~\mathrm dV.$$

Now given $U=\frac{3}{2}NkT-\frac{N^2 a}{V},$ I plugged it's derivatives into
 $$\mathrm dU=\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V~\mathrm dT+\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)_T~\mathrm dV,$$
from which I obtained
$$0=C_V~\mathrm dt+\left(P+\frac{N^2 a}{V^2} \right)_T~\mathrm dV=C_V~\mathrm dT + \frac{NkT}{V-Nb}~\mathrm dV,$$
using $V~ đW$'s equation.

Dividing by $T$ and integrating gives
$$C=\log{T^{C_V}}+\log{(V-Nb)^{Nk}},$$ which is equivalent to
$$C'=(V-Nb)^{Nk}T^{C_V},$$
for $C$ and $C'$ constants.

Now the expression so obtained seems very similar to what I was looking for, but I can't seem to get rid of the $Nk$ exponent. Anyone got a different approach to this problem, or a way to get the desired formula?

Comment: The result I get is $T^{3/2}(V-Nb)=\mathrm{const.}$ Are you sure the exponent is $C_{V}$ ?

Comment: That's what's in the problem set my professor gave me, but it might be wrong. How would you go and get the $3/2$ power?

Comment: Before integration, divide by $NkT$. Instead of $C_V$ you'll just get $3/2$. In the end you'll integrate $0=\frac{3}{2T}dT+\frac{1}{V-Nb}dV$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is $(V-Nb)T^{C_V/Nk}=\text{const}$, the problem statement is just wrong.