# Adiabata for Van der Waals equation

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

[Adiabata for ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Ideal_gas_(reversible_process))  has equation

$pV^\gamma = const.$

this allows calculate $p(V) = K/V^\gamma$, where K is some constant.

Is there similar equation and preferably function $p(V)$ for gas which follows [van der Waals equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) ?

Comment: Yes.  The derivation starts by expressing dU as a function of dT and dV for a van der Waals gas.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: You may find an indication how to go on by reading this old question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88548/adiabatic-expansion-in-van-der-waals-gas?rq=1 However, take into account that van der Waals equation of state alone doesn't allow a unique answer. One has to add explicitly additional information, like the dependence of $U$ on $T$.